# Firebase - when I push a profile object, I want to push by uid. instead of the default given id

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular

Firebase - when I push a profile object, I want to push by uid. instead of the default given id.

I'm using angular2, typescript and firebase.

I have a profiles json table.
The profile table has a list of profiles.

I'm trying to add a profile object.
I want the object core id to be the uid instead of the auto generated firebase one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can't do much, but you need to use `child` to create the id and then set the object. It would be something like:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com');
var profile = {
  id: 'your-own-id',
  name: 'Firebase'
};
ref.child('profiles').child(profile.id).set(profile);
```